# Python RNA getting the names of Vector axes. (eg "g" is color[1])

Tags: python

I've been playing around with [DriverTarget](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.DriverTarget.html?highlight=drivertarget#bpy.types.DriverTarget) `data_path` in a script. The data path, from the `target.id` object for the x location could be either "location.x" or "location[0]"

Is there a way of determining the name of the axes in different vector classes, like [Vector](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=euler#mathutils.Vector) ("xyz"), [Quaternion](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=euler#mathutils.Quaternion)("wxyz"), [Color](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=euler#mathutils.Color)("rgb") ... or "hsv" and so on.

Currently I'm just hardcoding a lookup table.

Comment: not sure if I understand the question right. Do you want to feed object.location[0] somewhere into a function and get "location.x" returned?

Comment: yeah I'll put some sample code in to clarify.  Basically yeah.. how do I know that x is index 0 of obj.location.

Comment: d=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  / v=Vector(d) / for c in "xyz": print(d.index( getattr(v,c))) ?

Comment: I still need to know it's "xyz"  would fail for  color.r = color(0) would need to be "rgb" and quaternion.w = q(0) from "wxyz".   If I hard code in the lookup table its just `"rgb".index("r")`  ... but how do I know its "rgb"? at the moment I check that it's a Color class and then assoc that with "rgb"... is there a way of getting "rbg" from the class?

Comment: if you look at mathutils_Vector.c line 2330 that seems to be an indication that there is no information from Python (of course this is just an hypothesis...)... Same thing for color, line 805

Comment: I understand nothing but below the line 2330 there is a Python script which could interest you

Comment: Yup still hard codes in axises = "xyzw"... looks like I'll stick with the classname: axises lookup table

Answer (score 2):

Guess you've tried this already, so forgive me if it doesn't suit your needs. It's also using hardcoding via a dictionary, the test runs based on the type of the property and the axis to test on:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Color, Euler, Quaternion


classMap = {
    Vector:'xyz',
    Color:'rgb',
    Euler:'xyz',
    Quaternion:'wxyz'
}


def returnIndex(_driverProp, _axis):
    dictVal = classMap[type(_driverProp)]
    return(dictVal.index(_axis))

print (returnIndex(bpy.context.object.rotation_quaternion, 'y'))
```